# On gui button is unclickable when placed over another button, why?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 buttons. One button is very large and is also a background (its a map). The other is a button that appears on top of the background button.

My ideas was that when clicking the background (world map), do one thing. And then when clicking the smaller button, for example representing a city, do something else. My second button is called after the first, and appears correctly, but is unclickable.

Even though the second button appears on top of the first, clicking on it does not result in it being activated. Instead the background ONLY gets clicked. Here is my code:

```
        // WorldMap map box
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(_mapWidthStart, _mapHeightStart, _mapAreaDimensions, _mapAreaDimensions), "", _standardGuiSkin.GetStyle("WorldMap_box_2")))
        {
            var y = ((Input.mousePosition.y * (ScrnHeight / Screen.height)) - _mapHeightStart) * (CurrentPlanetObject.Height / _mapAreaDimensions);
            var x = (Input.mousePosition.x * (ScrnWidth / Screen.width) - _mapWidthStart) * (CurrentPlanetObject.Width / _mapAreaDimensions);
            _currentDestinationCoordinates = x + ", " + y;
        }

        // Draw city icon.
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(relativeStartPosX + _mapWidthStart, relativeStartPosY + _mapHeightStart, 
            relativeWidth, relativeHeight), place.PlaceName, _standardGuiSkin.GetStyle(place.GuiStyle)))
        {
            _locationData1 = place.Description;
        }
```

Any idea why this might not be working. I wouldn't mind if they both got clicked, but the one on top doesn't respond at all.

To summarize, button 'city' is drawn on the button 'worldmap'. I expect button city to be pressed when clicking on it, but instead button worldmap is pressed and I see no activation of button city. It is unresponsive and doesn't fire.

**Edit:**

There seems to be some kind of weird behavior whereby the following happens. The first button to be created by OnGui() is the button that is clickable. But the button that is created last is the button that is visible.

Anyone who runs across this issue in the future may find this information useful. My fix was to split the world map button into two pieces, a box displaying the information and image appearing first, and a world map button with no image but having the desired functions appearing last so that it is overwritten where the city buttons appear.

Comment: Stop using `OnGui` and use [the new UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui).

Comment: @Draco18s, I prefer to separate my ui from the Unity front end (UI/Inspector, objects, etc), as much as possible. I have used the new UI, but I prefer the old script based UI over the new object based UI for this and other reasons. For example autogenerating menus and other displays from various data sources like databases, (and other operations), is much simpler and more intuitive from ongui in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the buttons are all in the same OnGUI() function, thet're drawn in the order they appear in your code. The last one is drawn on top of all the others. This makes it hard to handle overlaps because you want to intercept the top button, not the bottom. Joe Strout and some others posted a solution [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/corrected-gui-button-code-works-properly-with-layered-controls.96563/).
>
> If your buttons are in different OnGUI() functions (that is, different
>   scripts), use [GUI.depth](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-depth.html) to specify their rendering order.
>
> You can also wrap controls in GUI.Window, which prevents click-through
>   to lower controls.

This answer copy from [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/making-a-gui-button-first-priority-while-overlapping-a-different-gui-button.261715/).

At last ,Why on gui button is unclickable when placed over another button?

> Unity first checks and draws the first button so "a" is printed upon
>   clicking it. Then the second button is checked and drawn on top of the
>   first but the first button has already used the "click" event. So
>   overlapping objects inside the same OnGUI function can never happen
>   correctly.

The reason from [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-get-selectiongrid-to-draw-over-toggle-button.86621/).

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics of your code. However, try putting the city icon button as the foreground and the map as the background, this should be under 'layers' and allows you to setup logic like you require.

Comment: Any idea how to do this from code? All my ui is via script. I can post more code if necessary. I am using OnGui()